# Delays to be based on what elements are populated

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is create a function which will change the delays of each element based on if they are to be shown or not.

The delays are currently hard coded in which means that if the user does not choose to wire up any subheader texts, they are left waiting for a one second delay.

I have looked around but have not been able to find anything like this, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Below is a snippet of my code.

```js
 RemoveElements();

    $('#header').delay(1500).animate({'opacity': [1, "linear"]}, 500);
    $('#subheader1').delay(2000).animate({'opacity': [1, "linear"]}, 500);
    $('#text1').delay(2500).animate({'opacity': [1, "linear"]}, 500);
    $('#subheader2').delay(3000).animate({'opacity': [1, "linear"]}, 500);
    $('#text2').delay(3500).animate({'opacity': [1, "linear"]}, 500);
    $('#subheader3').delay(4000).animate({'opacity': [1, "linear"]}, 500);
    $('#text3').delay(4500).animate({'opacity': [1, "linear"]}, 500);

    function RemoveElements() { //REMOVE TEXT
      if ($('#header')[0].innerHTML == 'none') $('#header').css('display', 'none');
      if ($('#subheader1')[0].innerHTML == 'none') $('#subheader1').css('display', 'none');
      if ($('#text1')[0].innerHTML == 'none') $('#text1').css('display', 'none');
      if ($('#subheader2')[0].innerHTML == 'none') $('#subheader2').css('display', 'none');
      if ($('#text2')[0].innerHTML == 'none') $('#text2').css('display', 'none');
      if ($('#subheader3')[0].innerHTML == 'none') $('#subheader3').css('display', 'none');
      if ($('#text3')[0].innerHTML == 'none') $('#text3').css('display', 'none');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header">Header</h1>
<h2 id="subheader1" class="moveSub1">Subheader1</h2>
<p id="text1" class="movePara1">Text 1</p>
<h2 id="subheader2" class="moveSub2">none</h2>
<p id="text2" class="movePara2">Text 2</p>
<h2 id="subheader3" class="moveSub3">none</h2>
<p id="text3" class="movePara3">none</p>
```

Thank you for any help:)

Comment: Try and add `.stop(true, true)` before `.delay`

Comment: @darklightcode Thanks mate but this hasn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a fiddle. I hope this is what you were looking for. 
https://jsfiddle.net/wk2erc5q/

I outsourced some of the js stuff to the HTML so the JS looks like this now:

```
RemoveElements();

function RemoveElements() { 
  $('.check-element').each(function(){
    let element = $(this);
    if(element.html() == 'none'){
      setTimeout((function() {
       element.animate({'opacity': [0, "linear"]}, 500);
      }), element.attr('data-delay'));
    }
  });
}
```

If you want to set the elements to `display: none` and not just `opacity: 0` (since they will still need space), just replace the line in the set timeout with `element.hide();`

You could even work without the `data-delay` tag in the HTMl element when the animation time always increases by 500. Just set `let animationTime = 500` at the beginning of your `RemoveElements()` function and then after if-statement you can do `animationTime = animationTime + 500;`

---

https://jsfiddle.net/589xp4tf/

Comment: I am looking for the text to still fade in but to ignore any text that is still 'none'. Therefore the delay will skip over the 'none' element and go straight to the next element.

Comment: @Eddie check the second fiddle

Comment: Thanks mate, thats great!